# How can I contact a Slack team administrator if I'm not part of the team?

Tags: slack

I wanted to register a Slack team, but the most obvious team name for my purpose is already taken and I can not imagine who in their right mind, apart from me, would want to use that name.

So I thought that perhaps this is one of those accounts that someone registered but did not end up using and I was hoping to contact the team administrator and ask whether they would be willing to give up the slack domain.

Unfortunately when I go to https://my-funky-team-name.slack.com/signup [1] it says

> This team's administrator has not enabled email signups.

So my question is: is there a way to contact the administrator and is there any precedent of giving up team domains?

---

<sub>[1] not the actual team name</sub>